# Resource not found on polling message from google pubsub

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I have created 2 topics on a service account on google pub/sub(q_0 and q_abc). When I am reading message from q_0 it works fine but while polling from q_abc, I am getting the following exception. Both the queues have the same permissions given to it.

```
Sep 30, 2019 3:23:51 PM com.google.cloud.pubsub.v1.StreamingSubscriberConnection$1 onFailure
SEVERE: terminated streaming with exception
com.google.api.gax.rpc.NotFoundException: com.google.api.gax.rpc.NotFoundException: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: NOT_FOUND: Resource not found (resource=q_abc).
    at com.google.api.gax.rpc.ApiExceptionFactory.createException(ApiExceptionFactory.java:45)
    at com.google.cloud.pubsub.v1.StreamingSubscriberConnection$1.onFailure(StreamingSubscriberConnection.java:238)
    at com.google.api.core.ApiFutures$1.onFailure(ApiFutures.java:68)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$CallbackListener.run(Futures.java:1341)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$DirectExecutor.execute(MoreExecutors.java:398)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.executeListener(AbstractFuture.java:1027)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.complete(AbstractFuture.java:868)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.setException(AbstractFuture.java:713)
    at com.google.api.core.AbstractApiFuture$InternalSettableFuture.setException(AbstractApiFuture.java:95)
    at com.google.api.core.AbstractApiFuture.setException(AbstractApiFuture.java:77)
    at com.google.api.core.SettableApiFuture.setException(SettableApiFuture.java:52)
    at com.google.cloud.pubsub.v1.StreamingSubscriberConnection$StreamingPullResponseObserver.onError(StreamingSubscriberConnection.java:174)
    at com.google.api.gax.tracing.TracedResponseObserver.onError(TracedResponseObserver.java:103)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.ExceptionResponseObserver.onErrorImpl(ExceptionResponseObserver.java:84)
    at com.google.api.gax.rpc.StateCheckingResponseObserver.onError(StateCheckingResponseObserver.java:86)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcDirectStreamController$ResponseObserverAdapter.onClose(GrpcDirectStreamController.java:149)
    at io.grpc.PartialForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(PartialForwardingClientCallListener.java:39)
    at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:23)
    at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener$SimpleForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:40)
    at io.grpc.internal.CensusStatsModule$StatsClientInterceptor$1$1.onClose(CensusStatsModule.java:700)
    at io.grpc.PartialForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(PartialForwardingClientCallListener.java:39)
    at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:23)
    at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener$SimpleForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:40)
    at io.grpc.internal.CensusTracingModule$TracingClientInterceptor$1$1.onClose(CensusTracingModule.java:399)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.closeObserver(ClientCallImpl.java:510)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.access$300(ClientCallImpl.java:66)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl.close(ClientCallImpl.java:630)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl.access$700(ClientCallImpl.java:518)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1StreamClosed.runInternal(ClientCallImpl.java:692)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1StreamClosed.runInContext(ClientCallImpl.java:681)
    at io.grpc.internal.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:37)
    at io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.run(SerializingExecutor.java:123)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: com.google.api.gax.rpc.NotFoundException: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: NOT_FOUND: Resource not found (resource=q_abc).
    at com.google.api.gax.rpc.ApiExceptionFactory.createException(ApiExceptionFactory.java:45)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcApiExceptionFactory.create(GrpcApiExceptionFactory.java:72)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcApiExceptionFactory.create(GrpcApiExceptionFactory.java:60)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.ExceptionResponseObserver.onErrorImpl(ExceptionResponseObserver.java:82)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: NOT_FOUND: Resource not found (resource=q_abc).
    at io.grpc.Status.asRuntimeException(Status.java:533)
    ... 24 more
```

Can anyone help fixing this issue?

Answer (score 4):

To make sure the topic was really created by Google Cloud Pub/Sub you can run the following in the command-line:

```
gcloud pubsub topics list
```

Please, tell me if the topic really exist. We have to troubleshoot step by step in order to find the root of the problem.

Comment: Yes I checked the topics do exist on running the above command on cloud shell.

Comment: Hi, can you share some evidence the way you are setting the topics, please share a snippet of your code. Also I would like to see the results when you ran the command I shared with you in my past comment. Is clear that Pub/Sub is not recognizing the topic but I want to have a better view of the problem.

Comment: It worked fine now...before polling we have to register the subscription id on google cloud platform

Answer (score 1):

Before you need to create a suscription on your pubsub subject, after in resource name you put the name of this suscriber.